# tinymce text editor inner modals remove page scrollbar

Tags: javascript, tinymce

when I click a button that opens a modal:

[image]

it adds a class to "body" that called "tox-dialog__disable-scroll" and it disabling my page scrolling, I have looked at their documentation and found no solution for it except of overriding their class

Comment: *'found no solution for it except of overriding their class'* - because that's the only solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan cant prevent them from adding class to my "body"?

Comment: Not without modifying the code in their library, which is a bad idea in itself.